# file has not been pre-compiled issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have done a publish for my asp.net website through build>publish website option in visual studio 2010 and when deploy it in IIS 6 in staging environment it shows me "[filename].aspx has not been pre-compiled" for every page when i try to browse.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks Guys....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my live server did a IIS restart this caused the application error to be vanished.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling before the publish with Ctrl+Alt+B. Seems strange but happened to me once and that fixed it.